# Interaction model using lavaan package in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I want to fit the Kenny and Judd (1984) model below:

```
y = alpha + gamma1 * psi1 + gamma2 * psi2 + gamma3 * psi1 * psi2 + epsilon
```

The variables `psi1` and `psi2` are latent variables that are not directly observable. Kenny and Judd (1984) considered the case when there are two observable indicators `x1` and `x2` of `psi1` and two observable indicators `x3` and `x4` of `psi2`. I want to create this model in R using `lavaan` package.

## Code:

```
model <- '
psi1 =~ x1 + x2
psi2 =~ x3 + x4
'
fit <- sem(model,data=data)
```

Can anyone help me complete this code to obtain the interaction above?

Comment: I think you can start with defining the interaction variables themselves before adding them to the model, something like: intervar1 <- gamma1*psi1

Comment: Maybe this thread can be of any help:https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/lavaan/ZnRn9O6yWrA

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still searching in 2021, you can indeed specify categorical variables and interactions in lavaan (going up to three-way at present).

**(1)** You can use the group by function to specify a group with multiple levels, for example:

```
MyModel <- sem(my.lavaan.model, Data, group="MyMultiLevelGroup")
```

**(2)** You can also specify interaction terms using ":" within the lavaan model itself, for example:

```
my.lavaan.model <- '
y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2'
```

**(3)** Therefore, by combining steps (1) & (2) above you could specify a three-way interaction, between x1, x2 and MyMultiLevelGroup e.g.:

```
my.lavaan.model <- '
y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2'

MyModel <- sem(my.lavaan.model, Data, group="MyMultiLevelGroup")
```

This will display the results of an interaction between x1 and x2, at each level of MyMultiLevelGroup.